Wrapper-debug.conf is not getting created in MAC OS
I am doing hybris setup of 2211.24 in my local machine. I am able to start server withiut debug mode. But hen I try with ./hybrisserver.sh debug then my server startup is failing with an error message that wrapper-debug.conf file path doesnot exixt.
